# Can't see mistake in my PHP code, need fresh eyes

Tags: php, post, time

This should be piece of cake for someone experienced in PHP.
There's something wrong with my code & after staring / tweaking it for 2 days now I can't see the mistake.

**CHECK UPDATE BELOW!**

---

- This is suppose to change post status when set time is over
  ($draft_to_deleted_delay).
- **Problem:** not changing post status
- **I think problem is in status change code or date formats are not compatible in comparison** but Im not great with PHP
  yet & don't know for sure.
- This is all wrapped in function which is called with WP cron - cron works, checked it with plugin.
- No errors!

---

**ALL CODE:**

```
// Covert date input
$draft_to_deleted_delay = '00-00-00-00-10-00'; //YY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS <-- year-month-day-hour-minute-second

$draft_to_deleted_delay     = explode('-', $draft_to_deleted_delay);
$draft_to_deleted_delay     = new DateInterval(
    'P'.$draft_to_deleted_delay[0].'Y'.
    $draft_to_deleted_delay[1].'M'.
    $draft_to_deleted_delay[2].'D'.
    'T'.$draft_to_deleted_delay[3].'H'.
    $draft_to_deleted_delay[4].'M'.
    $draft_to_deleted_delay[5].'S'
);

// Get current date
$now = new DateTime();

// Get all the unpublished posts
$unpublished_posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'meta_key'          => 'draftDate', //This value is saved as strftime('%F %T') when post gets status "draft"
    'post_status'       => 'draft'
));

while($unpublished_posts->have_posts()) {
    $unpublished_posts->the_post();
    $draft = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'draftDate', true);
    if(!empty($draft)) {

        // Date comparison
        $dt = new DateTime($draft);
        $dt->add($draft_to_deleted_delay);
        if($dt < $now) {

            // Expiration date reached, change to any status, "pending" in this example
            wp_update_post(array('ID' => get_the_ID(), 'post_status' => 'pending'));
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Everything is fine now and code is updated!

- **Main reason why this didn't work and suprisingly 40+ people didn't notice: ">" was facing the wrong way.**
- **Also post status change was wrong.**

Never program when you're very tired.

Comment: Does your script actually run the function `wp_update_post()`? Check that first.

Comment: seems like this could have been accomplished in the db using an event

Comment: @AWA I don't really know WP good enough, but if it's a php script you could access it directly with your browser and make an output in your script.

Comment: You corrected the code and now the question doesn't make any sense for the users that come and read it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked some docs (...) and this line looks fishy (loop pointer change, doesn't return anything):

```
$this_post = $unpublished_posts->the_post();
```

I think you wanted `get_post()` or sth. I would simply call:

```
wp_update_post(array('ID' => get_the_ID(), 'post_status' => 'pending'));
```

This function will gather current data with `get_post(ID)` and merge both anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used / worked with Wordpress so can off no guidance with any aspect of that - but what you are describing seems like something that the database could and should be able to handle easily using Events.
Think of an Event like a 'scheduled task' in windows.

A basic example of an 'Event' in the database (mySql etc).
You might want to [look at this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html)

```
create event `evUpdateDraftStatus`
    on schedule
        every '1' day_hour starts '2015-08-22'
    on completion preserve
    enable
    comment 'every 1 hour(s) call a stored procedure that processes Drafts.'
    do call spUpdateDrafts()
```

To enable events in the db run this cmd: `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`

[See the reference for more info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)

A basic example of a stored procedure that gets called by the event.

```
create procedure `spUpdateDrafts`( IN `param_days` INT )
    language sql
    not deterministic
    contains sql
    sql security definer
    comment 'Update drafts'

begin
    /* Perform sql operations, for example: */
    declare days integer default 0;
    set @days=cast(param_days as unsigned);

    update `table` set `draftstatus`=0 
        where `draftstatus`=1 and timestampdiff( day, `draft_created_date`, now() ) > @days;
end
```